# Is there a way to use like this in Sequelize in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
include: [
            {
              model: ChannelPlayList,
              if(type==1){
                include: [
                  {
                    model: Music,
                  },
                ],
              }
              else{
                include: [
                  {
                    model: Record,
                  },
                ]
              }
```

if `ChannelList.type==1` I want to include Music schema, else include Record schema.
is there a way to do like this in Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that this can be done, here are some of the ways:

Method 1:

```
// Ternary operator works well if just one table or the other
include: [
    {
        model: ChannelPlayList,
        include: [type == 1 ? Music : Record],
    }
]
```

Method 2:

```
// Depends on table names
let table;
if (type == 1) {
    table = 'music';
} else {
    table = 'record';
}

include: [
    {
        model: ChannelPlayList,
        include: [table], // Uses table name string in place of model
    }
]
```

The key is that whatever your array element is set to will be the table that will be included in your query.

The above assumes you know the `type` beforehand.

You may need to retrieve `type` first if it comes from the ChannelPlayList table, or you could include both models and just use the one that you need: `include: [Music, Record]`